# LinkedIn API timeIntervals object

Tags: linkedin-api

The documentation for the API for getting follower statistics says, that I can provide the field "timeIntervals" in the API request. The documentation says that "timeIntervals" is an object, but an object of which class? What kind of format is required?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

I think that it means that `timeIntervals` is just an object of type... `timeIntervals`.
Infact if you look through the documentation you'll find that the `timeIntervals` is an object with the following structure:

- `timeIntervals`:

  - `timeGranularityType` -> `string`
  - `timeRange` -> `object` having two attributes:

    - `start` -> `long` (unix time in ms)
    - `end` -> `long` (unix time in ms)

You can than use these attribute in the request query:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A2414183&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1551398400000,end:1552003200000),timeGranularityType:DAY)
```